# NodeJs micro services shared dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, microservices, dependency-management

i have built a microservices application using NodeJs . i have building this app for 4 month now and it starts to be big. i have used private modules to share code between the services but now i face anther problem.

i am getting duplicate code for requiring this modules(and public modules) as many of them are being used in all the services and are called in my index file.

so what i have try to do is build anther private module that it`s purpose is to include all this modules dependencies and control all the updates .

that works good, the problem is the IDE "phpstorm" screams on me because now those dependencies are not in the service package.json  and also i dont have autocomplete on them(same reason) .

is there a way to let the package json to use this dependencies from that package , or maybe anther technique to achieve this

Comment: Okay from what I understand you've created a npm module that includes all the dependencies and exposes these same in all your micro-services? IDE is not providing auto-complete is that the issue?

Comment: well basically yes

Comment: which IDE you're using?

Comment: PHPSTORM ......

Comment: oh I see, intellij might be providing a separate IDE for node js could you look at it, I use Atom or VS code(sometimes) for node related stuff.

Comment: well you point me to the right direction its not a complete answer but it gives me autocomplete . i found this link to that helps me  https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/208376385-How-to-unexclude-node-modules-in-2016-2-2-        you can put it in your answer and ill accept it

Comment: glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ might be providing a separate IDE for node js could you look at it, I use Atom or VS code(sometimes) for node related stuff. Maybe take a look at [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/node-js.html) as well.